# How to call kill and yank function from Hammerspoon or Karabiner

Tags: macos, hammerspoon, karabiner

OSX default kill(`ctrl + k`) and yank(`ctrl + y`) function doesn't work when using Thai or Korean input mode.
Other key bindings for cursor movements are also disabled.

So I'm trying to emulate the function by using `Hammerspoon`.
But I couldn't find out how to call the `kill` and `yank` function from hammerspoon.

I could only implemente for cursor movements by this code.

```
local EmacsKeyMap = hs.hotkey.modal.new()

local function sendKey(mods, key)
   return function()
      hs.eventtap.keyStroke(mods, key, 10000)
   end
end

local function bindToEmacsKeyMap(mods, key, func)
   EmacsKeyMap:bind(mods, key, func, nil, func)
end

bindToEmacsKeyMap({'ctrl'}, 0, sendKey({'command'}, 'left')) -- C-a
bindToEmacsKeyMap({'ctrl'}, 14, sendKey({'command'}, 'right')) -- C-e
bindToEmacsKeyMap({'ctrl'}, 11, sendKey({}, 'left')) -- C-b
bindToEmacsKeyMap({'ctrl'}, 3, sendKey({}, 'right')) -- C-f
bindToEmacsKeyMap({'ctrl'}, 45, sendKey({}, 'down')) -- C-n
bindToEmacsKeyMap({'ctrl'}, 35, sendKey({}, 'up')) -- C-p
bindToEmacsKeyMap({'ctrl'}, 4, sendKey({}, 'delete')) -- C-h

EmacsKeyMap:enter()
```

I googled some hammerspoon scripts for emacs emulation, but they are just using key strokes for the function.

Is there a way to call the kill and yank directly from a Hammerspoon script?

#### Edit 2019/02/21

If `Karabiner` or other applications can accomplish same behavior, I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to make it with `Hammerspoon`, but by following explanation of [this website](https://zariganitosh.hatenablog.jp/entry/20101026/text_key_binding) I edited `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`. Then all text key binding works as I expected.

```
{
    "^ฟ" = "moveToBeginningOfParagraph:"; /* ctrl-a */
    "^ฤ" = "moveToBeginningOfParagraphAndModifySelection:"; /* ctrl-A */
    "^ิ" = "moveBackward:"; /* ctrl-b */
    "^ฺ" = "moveBackwardAndModifySelection:"; /* ctrl-B */
    "^ก" = "deleteForward:"; /* ctrl-d */
    "^ำ" = "moveToEndOfParagraph:"; /* ctrl-e */
    "^ฎ" = "moveToEndOfParagraphAndModifySelection:"; /* ctrl-E */
    "^ด" = "moveForward:"; /* ctrl-f */
    "^โ" = "moveForwardAndModifySelection:"; /* ctrl-F */
    "^้" = "deleteBackward:"; /* ctrl-h */
    "^า" = "deleteToEndOfParagraph:"; /* ctrl-k */
    "^ส" = "centerSelectionInVisibleArea:"; /* ctrl-l */
    "^ื" = "moveDown:"; /* ctrl-n */
    "^์" = "moveDownAndModifySelection:"; /* ctrl-N */
    "^น" = (
        "insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:",
        "moveBackward:",
    ); /* ctrl-o */
    "^ย" = "moveUp:"; /* ctrl-p */
    "^ญ" = "moveUpAndModifySelection:"; /* ctrl-P */
    "^ะ" = "transpose:"; /* ctrl-t */
    "^ฮ" = "pageDownAndModifySelection:"; /* ctrl-V */
    "^อ" = "pageDown:"; /* ctrl-v */
    "^ั" = "yank:"; /* ctrl-y */
}
```